# Passing instance methods as objects

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to generate method wrappers dynamically. For a proof of concept, I want to have a wrapper that does nothing. The code would look something like this:

```
cSomeClassName testObject = new cSomeClassName();

dynamic wrapperObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

foreach (var method in typeof(cSomeClassName).GetMethods())
{
    wrapperObject.Add(method.Name, 
                     (method.GetParameters()) => testObject.CallMethodWithParams(method.Name, method.GetParameters()));
}
```

Making a call to

```
testObject.MethodName(params);
```

Would now be equivelant to

```
wrapperObject.MethodName(params);
```

I realize this is a very broken example implementation, but I'm not sure how to improve on it.

Comment: Does it have to be Expando? Can't you implement your own dynamic with overridden TryInvokeMember?

Comment: Maybe? I just chose an Expando because I know that I can add methods with `expandoObj.Add(methodName, methodDefinition)`. The real issue here is `methodDefinition`. As far as I know, a lambda can't have a dynamic argument list. I'm hoping a solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

After much jury rigging, I give you the solution:

```
class cMethodExecutor
{
    private ArrayList m_ArgumentList;
    private Object m_CallObject;
    private string m_MethodName;

    public cMethodExecutor(Object iObject)
    {
        m_CallObject = iObject;
        m_ArgumentList = new ArrayList();
        m_MethodName = "";
    }

    public void SetMethodName(string iMethodName)
    {
        m_MethodName = iMethodName;
    }

    public void AddArgument(Object iArgument)
    {
        m_ArgumentList.Add(iArgument);
    }

    public object Execute()
    {
        return m_CallObject.GetType().GetMethod(m_MethodName).Invoke(m_CallObject, m_ArgumentList.ToArray());
    }
}


public delegate object ParamsFunc(params object[] iArgs);


//For now, we're going to just fall through to the original object:
IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();

foreach (var method in typeof(cTestTarget).GetMethods())
{

    Console.WriteLine("Adding method: " + method.Name + "\n");

    obj.Add(method.Name, new ParamsFunc( inputList =>
    {
        cMethodExecutor newExecutor = new cMethodExecutor(iTestTarget);
        newExecutor.SetMethodName(method.Name);
        foreach (var param in inputList)
        {
            newExecutor.AddArgument(param);
        }

        return newExecutor.Execute();

    }));
}
```

Any methods that existed in iTestTarget now exist in obj, and dispatch to the original iTestTarget.